# How to have multiple groups by user

Tags: django

How to have different groups for a user

with one user and one group, I have the test :

```
ungroupe = Group.objects.get(user= current_user)
```

How to do the test if I have one user and two groups ?

Answer (score 0):

> groups = Group.objects.filter(user=current_user)

will give you a QuerySet you can iterate over that has all of the groups in it.

Comment: if user : group1, group2, groups = Group.objects.get(user= current_user) will return the error MultipleObjectsReturn et() returned more than one Group

Comment: Is this still applicable for Django-1.6 using AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL contains the dotted path to your custom user model; in code, you typically want `contrib.auth.get_user_model()`, which returns the actual model class. If you're writing code that might be used on multiple sites (or where you might change the user model to a custom one), you'd be smart to always use the result of that rather than referring to the User model itself. But your Group model should point to the real user model, assuming you set the custom model up properly.